# In Spring Aspect programming how to differentiate a method call and Rest Call

Tags: java, spring, aspect

I have a service using a method and I have actual method call also using it. can we differentiate between both in Aspect programming.

for eg.

```
public class AccountProcessorImpl implements AccountProcessor{

public Response calculateBalance(Account accountInfo){
//some implementaion
}
} 

@Path("account")
public class AccountService{
    @InjectParam
    AccountProcessor accountProcessor;
    public Response getBalance (Account accountInfo)
    {
        return accountProcessor.calculateBalance(accountInfo);
    }
}
```

I have included the method calculateBalance in my Aspect program to do some authentication(PointCut()). Now I want to use this method just as a method call. Now the method fails due to the authentication. so Can I differentiate some how? like do authentication only if its a Rest API call and no need authentication if its a method call

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have layers (web, service, etc.), you could put security on the web layer and not the service layer.

Comment: exactly its all about security